# add rows then fill those rows with data from collection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to add rows dynamically into a word table and then fill those rows with data from collection.
Here is what i try to do but i does not work well.

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(nbTable).Select
Selection.InsertRowsBelow nbR
addTableRows = ActiveDocument.Tables(nbTable).Rows.Count

ActiveDocument.Tables(nbTable).Columns(nbC).Cells(intCell).Range.Text = txt

ActiveDocument.Tables(nbTable).Columns(nbC).Cells(intCell).Select
Selection.Font.TextColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
```

The problem is that when i do this i get an error saying the rows do not exists. The thing is the rows add after i get the error and i cannont fill the rows with the data i need.
Can anyone help me please. I'm new to this environment.

Comment: if row is getting added, have you tried `ActiveDocument.Tables(nbTable).Rows(addTableRows).Cells(intCell).Range.Text = txt`.where `addTableRows` would be the last row and  `intcell` is the column. I generally follow this syntax and never failed. I failed to understand the what you trying refer by`Columns(nbC).Cells(intCell)`. Also better to avoid selection. `.......Cells(...).Range.Font.TextColor` would suffice.

Comment: @AhmedAU i was refering to different columns cause i have to fill different columns with different data from my collection.

Comment: Since you getting an error saying the rows do not exists. it means the variable (may be `Intcell`) is greater than `Tables(nbTable).Rows.Count`, could help if the variables or full code is given. otherwise try with syntax in previous comment

Comment: @AhmedAU 
        Call addTableRows(dataC.Count / 2, nbT)
        For i = 2 To dataC.Count / 2
           For j = 1 To 2
                ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Rows(i).Cells(j).Range.Text = dataC(i + 1)
            Next j
        Next i
    End With

but i still get an error and the process is slower, like really slow

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be better expressed as:

```
Dim r As Long
With ActiveDocument.Tables(nbTable)
  For r = 1 To nbR
    .Rows.Add (.Rows(.Rows.Count))
  Next
  With .Cell(intCell, nbC).Range
    .Text = "txt"
    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
  End With
End With
```

That said, nothing you've posted tells us what values nbTable, nbR, nbC, or intCell contain, how many tables there are in the document, or whether the referenced table has the applicable number of rows & columns, etc., so it's impossible for us to know whether any of those values is valid in any particular case. It's also not apparent what purpose addTableRows is supposed to serve.

Comment: I'm sorry for not beeing clear enough. nbTable = 3 and in the document i got 7 tables,
nbC is the column where i want to add the value either 1 or 2,  nbR is the number of rows to be added to the table ( cause i got a collection of data and i need to fill these rows with that data). The intCell variable represents the value of  "for i =2 to mycollection.count /2". I think that's it.

Comment: it works quiet well, i've made the changes i needed and it works, Thanks a lot.